# Running python code on multiple files in folder and writing them to separate files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a code to run a script on multiple files in a folder.  I am able to run the code on each file however it is only saving to one output file then rewriting over that file.  How can I get this code to save the output to separate files?  Preferably with a similar name to each original file.  This is what I have thus far.

```
import os, re
import pandas as pd
directory = os.listdir('C:/Users/user/Desktop/NOV')
os.chdir('C:/Users/user/Desktop/NOV')

for file in directory:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True)
    df = df.resample('1min').mean()
    df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="1min"))
    df.to_csv("newfile.csv", na_rep='NaN')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it obviously will always write to the same file because you are always giving the same file name in `to_csv`. Use `os.path.basename` to create a new file name based on the old one without extension:

```
df.to_csv(os.path.basename(file) + "-processed.csv", na_rep='NaN')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the file name in the last line in each iteration of the loop.
Something like `for i, file in enumerate(directory):` and then `df.to_csv("new_" + file + ".csv", na_rep='NaN')` will do.

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

- use `glob.glob` instead of `os.listdir` to filter out files which aren't `csv` files
- don't perform a `os.chdir`, this is bad practice because other modules may not be aware that you changed the current directory, also changing dir twice as relative will fail, using `glob.glob` is nice to avoid that.
- create a file with the same name but with `"new_"` prefix in the same directory (running twice will create `"new_new_` file, though)

code:

```
import os, re, glob
import pandas as pd

input_dir = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/NOV'

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_dir,"*.csv")):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True)
    df = df.resample('1min').mean()
    df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="1min"))
    new_filename = os.path.join(input_dir,"new_"+os.path_basename(file))
    df.to_csv(new_filename, na_rep='NaN')
```

Comment: Thank you why would os.chdir be considered bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

The 'file' you've referenced in your for-loop should be the string of the file you are manipulating in your directory.

```
for file in directory:
    print file
    #oldfile.csv
```

You can use this to make a new file with a reference to the original. Something like this:

```
for file in directory:
    df.to_csv("Output -" + file, na_rep='NaN') #make this the last line of your for-loop.
    #File will be called 'Output - oldfile.csv'
```